# How can I use radio buttons correctly in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, radio-button

im new to rails and i want to include radio buttons to my Rails Application. I dont know if i have to install gems or anything else. I just saw this code in another app:

```
    <% @roles.each do |role| %>
        <div class="radio">

          <% radio_ %>
          <%= radio_button_tag "user[role_ids][]", role.id, @user.roles.include?(role) %>
          <%= role.description %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
```

So i created user roles and ids so i can use those buttons. My Cursor above               <% radio_ %> says "cannot find radio_".

Comment: have you try remove that line and what happen if you remove?

Comment: Then i recieve the error message undefined method 'roles'. Where i have to define them ?

Comment: Are you sure you `User` have `has_many` relationship with `roles` ?

Comment: Ah so blind... thank you mate :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use check-box if you are looking for multiple selection of roles,  cause in radio button you can choose only one role, also I am assuming you are using rolify gem, so better to use has_role? method.

```
@roles=current_user.roles

<%=@roles.each do |role|
    <div class='radio'>
    <%=label_tag role.name %>
    <%=check_box_tag "user[role_ids][]", role.id, current_user.has_role?(role) %>
<% end %>
```